# Error in glmm.hp: Analysis not conducted. Insufficient number of predictors

Tags: r, lme4

I'm wondering if anyone out there has experience with the glmm.hp hierarchical partitioning package in r.

I'm running some analyses to examine the impacts of marine heatwaves on coral bleaching. My response is bleaching, my fixed factors are five marine heatwave metrics (mean intensity, maximum intensity, cumulative intensity, duration and maximum absolute temperature). My random factor is Ecoregion.

I'm running the following code:

```
mod3 = glmer(Coral2~`intensity_mean(mean)`+`intensity_max(max)`+`intensity_cumulative(total)`+intensity_max_abs+
               `Duration(total)`+Point_in_range +(1|as.factor(Ecoregion)), data=Coral_ALL_J_S, family = binomial, weights = Coral_ALL_J_S$n)

r.squaredGLMM(mod3)
summary(mod3)
glmm.hp(mod3)
plot(glmm.hp(mod3))
```

When I get to the glmm.hp line, I get the following error message

```
> glmm.hp(mod3)
Error in glmm.hp(mod3) : 
  Analysis not conducted. Insufficient number of predictors.
```

Does anyone have any idea why this might be? If I exclude my random factor and run the model as a glm, the hierarchical partitioning works absolutely fine.

Here is a small subset of my data:

```
> Coral_ALL_J_S
# A tibble: 412 × 10
   Ecoregion Coral Coral2     n `Duration(total)` `intensity_mean(mean)` `intensity_max(max)` `intensity_cumulative(total)` intensity_max_abs Point_in_range
   <chr>     <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>             <dbl>                  <dbl>                <dbl>                         <dbl>             <dbl>          <dbl>
 1 Andaman    0    0          4                 5                   1.60                 1.84                          8.02              30.5         0.267 
 2 Andaman    0    0          1                 5                   1.60                 1.84                          8.02              30.5         0.267 
 3 Andaman    0    0          1                 5                   1.60                 1.84                          8.02              30.5         0.269 
 4 Andaman    0    0          1                 5                   1.60                 1.84                          8.02              30.5         0.272 
 5 Andaman    0    0          2                 9                   1.28                 1.67                         11.5               31.7         0.0414
 6 Andaman    0    0          1                12                   1.58                 1.97                         18.7               30.2         0.292 
 7 Andaman    0    0          1                18                   1.30                 1.89                         23.4               31.7         0.0265
 8 Andaman    0    0          1                18                   1.30                 1.89                         23.4               31.7         0.0265
 9 Andaman    2.25 0.0225     1                 7                   1.28                 1.75                          8.93              31.0         0.219 
10 Andaman    6.25 0.0625     1                 6                   1.09                 1.54                          6.53              31.2         0.0753
# ℹ 402 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

Apologies if I am missing any information that might be needed to answer this - I'm new to posting in stack overflow!

Many thanks,
Katie